# Is "that" the right complement of the verb "require"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage

Here are original sentences: "Sometimes a creative problem is so difficult that it **requires people to connect their imaginations together**; the answer arrives only if we collaborate"

But how about the following sentences: " Sometimes a creative problem is so difficult that **it requires (that) people connect their imaginations together**; the answer arrives only if we collaborate"

I want to know whether the latter sentences are grammatically correct.
Can you help me?

Comment: The last sentence is grammatically correct, but unnecessarily complex. The infinitive is simpler and requires less processing and no agreement.

Comment: @JohnLawler And you could also put "require" into the infinitive, as in: *... the problem is so difficult as to require people to connect...*, making it simpler still.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, grammatically correct. It could also be written as

> "Sometimes a creative problem is so difficult that it requires people *to connect* their imaginations together; the answer arrives only if we collaborate."

, using the infinitive instead in accordance with its status as the direct object of "it requires" (the indirect object here is "people"). Or perhaps simply looking at the connection between people's minds as taking the role of the direct object would make more sense.

Or even something like

> "Sometimes a creative problem is so difficult *as to require* people to connect their imaginations together; the answer arrives only if we collaborate."

could work as well, meaning roughly the same thing as the first sentence.